# Doctrine2 Migrations... access to entities for content update

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, database-migration

I've started using Doctrine Migrations and I'm loving it... well, at least I did until today :-)
As part of the migrations I need to update the menu table to add new functionalities to the app. I know inserting content as part of an migration is not encouraged, but I can't fin a better way to handle it. Inserting per se is not a problem, but in my case the table makes use of NestedTree and also has a foreign key that needs to be set.

So in order to fill in all that data I need to query the database to get some values before inserting the new content.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355678/doctrine2-migration-using-dbal-instead-of-this-addsql?rq=1) that you can use PDO by accessing the connection using `$this->connection`. It's not as easy (in this case) as using entities, but it works!